# npm command couldn't be executed - dashlane/cli

Tags: json, powershell, npm, command-line

I am trying to install the [dashlane-cli](https://github.com/Dashlane/dashlane-cli) using PowerShell.
Unfortunately, there is a problem with the installation. PowerShell says that the command could not be executed. It reads the command from the package.json from the dashlane-cli. There is probably an error in there, but I can't find it. It tries to open a shell file called "prepare-pkg.sh".
Does anyone have a hint how I can solve the problem?
[Scripts in the package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6xlc.png)
[PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xEII.png)

Comment: wait, do you mean different dashlane-cli? what i found from the official github is this https://github.com/Dashlane/dashlane-cli . and what you mention is 4 years old without update too. so i think its deprecated source code?

Comment: Yes, sorry had two windows open, meant this one: https://github.com/Dashlane/dashlane-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see on your screenshot, you try to run `npm run pkg`, which "make" the binary of the dashlane-cli app itself.

What should you do to install is downloading this https://github.com/Dashlane/dashlane-cli/releases/download/v1.0.0/dcli-win.exe (I assume you are on windows because you are using Powershell) and just run it.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hey man, thanks ^^ We are encoutering a heatwave atm, you're absoltuley right.